# What aspects of adoption are, or are not, on topic at Parenting.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is an Adoption.SE [under consideration in Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86249/adoption) at the moment. [One discussion post states that it is already covered by Parenting.SE](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20404/adoption-is-covered-by-parenting-se):

> Adoption is certainly a very worth-while topic (speaking as an adoptive parent myself) - but it is clearly covered by Parenting.SE.

As one response to the discussion question puts it:

> Adoption doesn't just affect the people adopting, it also affects the
>   people being adopted, the people giving up their child(ren) for
>   adoption, and the birth/adoptive family of the adoptee. There are
>   plenty of adoption related issues that would be off topic at Parenting
>   SE....

---

The only discussion of adoption-related issues on our meta is [Are questions about becoming a parent on topic?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/573/are-questions-about-becoming-a-parent-on-topic) which concluded *yes*, they're on topic. (In addition, we've got a handful of questions tagged [adoption](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption).) There isn't much discussion beyond that, however. It's still early in the beta process, so not clear whether Adoption.SE will be able to take on questions that we may be unable to answer. However, it may be useful for us to better define adoption-related questions. **We've established that "adoption" is on topic for our site, but are there related or sub-topics that might not be on topic?**

To be clear, I am not asking this question to detract from that site's validity or potential in any way. If they successfully launch, then we know what sorts of questions would be good candidates for migration (e.g., questions we can't answer). If they don't successfully launch, then we can still provide a StackExchange location for adoption-related questions (although perhaps with a narrower scope). Either way, having a meta discussion can better define topicality of a range of adoption questions, useful to refer to in future.

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking of anything that's not clearly on-topic outside of questions specific to the adoption *process*, which require expert knowledge or people with specific experience. We could *say* it's on topic, but then we still may have trouble get the answers.

Comment: As @CreationEdge noted, depends on who the target expert audience for a new site. If it's adoption professionals, there may be some merit to having a separate site for those experts. If not, they would have just as much lack of expert answers there as here, so there's no point in separate site

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can think of that I would consider potentially off-topic would be questions asking for legal advice related to adoption issues.

I think everything else should be on topic.

Comment: THIS. And legal advice should be offtopic on **any** SE (evel legal.SE that is finally working its way through Area51), including Adoption.SE

Comment: I know over at Workplace.SE legal topics are *strictly* off topic. Any question that is remotely phrased like it's asking for legal advice gets DV and closed quickly

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of stuff that adoptive parents go through that birth parents don't.  This isn't limited to the (off topic) legal stuff.

For example: professionals inspect and assess your home, and professionals question and assess you before you get the child.

I am happy for those questions to be asked here, although I do understand the desire to have a more focussed adoption.SE site.

(I try to be inclusive of adoptive parenting but I might not always get the language right. I'm happy for advice!)